# ¿Cómo puedo a mandar a imprimir desde SweetAlert2?

Tags: javascript, html5, sweetalert2

Tengo el siguiente Script para mandar una alerta (SweetAlert2) antes de mostrar la ventana de impresión, la cual mando a llamar con window.print, pero al confirmar me muestra la ventana de impresión con los datos en blanco, ¿Alguna solución a ello?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

            const $boton = document.querySelector("#generar");
            $boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: '¿Quieres mandar a imprimir?',
                    showDenyButton: true,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Imprimir',
                    denyButtonText: `Cancelar`,
                }).then((result) => {
                    /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        window.print();
                        folios();
                        insertarBD();
                        cambiarBD();
                        calcularTotal();

                    } else if (result.isDenied) {
                        Swal.fire('Impresión cancelada')

                    }

                })

                // Enviar datos a la BD

            });

        });
```

[image: De esta manera queda la vista previa de impresión cuando está dentro de SweetAlert2]

Comment: No estoy muy seguro, pero, si invocas a la impresion antes de tus funciones, ningun dato va a llegar a a hoja, prueba invocando a la impresion al final de tu if, por ejemplo: `if (result.isConfirmed) { folios();  insertarBD();  cambiarBD(); calcularTotal(); window.print(); }`

Comment: @EvilFearzZ concuerdo. Tendrías que cargar la impresión (el documento e información a imprimir) y luego `window.print();`